# How to echo a output of a shell script, outside the script

Tags: shell

We have a shell script in the following location.

```
/opt/shellscript/test1.sh
```

Content of test1.sh file.

```
USERVALUES = P1321,testusername@example.com
USERVALUES1 ="$USERVALUES"
echo "Value of USERVALUES1 is $USERVALUES1"
```

We need to execute another script

```
/opt/shellscript/test2.sh
```

Content of the test2.sh file.

```
    chmod +x /opt/shellscript/test1.sh
    sh /opt/shellscript/test1.sh
    echo "Value of USERVALUES1 from script test1.sh is $USERVALUES1"
```

We need to get the output as below.

```
Value of USERVALUES1 from script test1.sh is P1321,testusername@example.com
```

Could someone help on the same, how we can achieve this use case.

Comment: Please copy and paste the statements always verbatim. Your script `test1.sh` would not run in the way you wrote it, due to the incorrect use of spaces.

Comment: Aside from this error, this is a design problem. Your script should not set variables **and** do something else (`echo` for instance). Separate them - one single script which is doing only the variable setting, and then you can source it from both test1.sh and test2.sh.

Comment: BTW, I took the liberty to remove the _bash_ tag, because your question obviously is not about bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Edit test1.sh (remove spaces)

```
USERVALUES=P1321,testusername@example.com
USERVALUES1=$USERVALUES
echo "Value of USERVALUES1 is $USERVALUES1"
```

2. To fetch vars in `test2.sh` form `test1.sh` you need to:

```
source test1.sh
```

3. cat test2.sh

```
chmod +x /opt/shellscript/test1.sh
# source /opt/shellscript/test1.sh
. /opt/shellscript/test1.sh
sh /opt/shellscript/test1.sh
echo "Value of USERVALUES1 from script test1.sh is $USERVALUES1"
```

Comment: AFIK, _source_ is not allowed in POSIX shell. May I suggest that do a `.` instead?

Comment: you're right, thanks, edited script with ```.``` instead of ```source```

Comment: Of course in your solution, the text _Value of USERVALUES1 is ...._ would be printed twice, once in the `.` statement and then in the `sh ....` statement. See my comment to the OP about a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access internal data of another process. The other process has to expose the data. Typically by writing the data to a file descriptor: standard output, a pipe or a temporary file.